# Conditionally showing values in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array which has some values that am storing to an API,, I want to show the field that has a value and omit the others but aint sure how to write the logic in PHP,,

~ Kindly assist?

```
array:5 [
  "child1Dob" => "2018-11-07",
  "child2Dob" => null,
  "child3Dob" => null,
  "child4Dob" => null,
  "child5Dob" => null,
]
```

Comment: You want to do so in a loop or simply remove null from the array and loop the clean array?

Comment: Or `array_filter`, for that matter.

Comment: @DiogoSanto I want to pass only the field that has a value

Comment: That why I asked the above question

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca How can I use it,, kindly explain via an example

Comment: `$arrayWithoutNull = array_diff($array, array(null));`

Comment: Is it just me, or does it seem like this question is just someone's course work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$b = array_filter($a, function($k) { return $k!=null; });
```

Working example [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6b2c439d5d37212e0b652248893e270da37c9ce2).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to only keep the values that are not `Null`.
Try like this.

```
array_filter($array);
```